# how to check if exist two key value pairs in the same dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which looks like this:

```
[{'event_date__count': 5,
  'event_type': 'NO',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 5)},
 {'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'NO',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)},
{'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'CL',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)},
{'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'PV',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)}]
```

also have a list which contains the unique possible values of the event type field:

```
event_types = ['No', 'CL', 'PV', 'TT']
```

what I want is to check if all the possible combination of the event_type are exist for the event_week and if not than append a list with a new dict item with a same event_week and a missing event_type

So taking the below example the aimed result would be (added the items with 0 count) :

```
[{'event_date__count': 5,
  'event_type': 'NO',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 5)},
{'event_date__count': 0,
  'event_type': 'CL',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 5)},
{'event_date__count': 0,
  'event_type': 'PV',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 5)},
{'event_date__count': 0,
  'event_type': 'TT',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 5)},
{'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'NO',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)},
{'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'CL',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)},
{'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'PV',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)} ,
{'event_date__count': 0,
  'event_type': 'TT',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)}]
```

I am pretty new in python os it might be easy but would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Please show your attempts. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, extract the unique dates from list of dictionaries like this,

```
event_types = ['NO', 'CL', 'PV', 'TT']
dict_list = [{'event_date__count': 5,
  'event_type': 'NO',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 5)},
 {'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'NO',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)},
{'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'CL',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)},
{'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'PV',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)}]

dates = []
for item in dict_list:
    dates.append(item['event_week'])

dates = list(set(dates))
print(dates)
```

Output:

```
[datetime.date(2018, 11, 5), datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)]
```

Now, loop through `event_types` and for each event, take a date from `dates` list and for each date, check the combination of `event_type` and `date` and if it does not exists, append it to list of dictionaries otherwise just ignore it. Do it like this,

```
for type in event_types:
    found = False
    for date in dates:
        for item in dict_list:
            if item['event_type'] == type and item['event_week'] == date:
                found = True
        if (found == False):
            dict_list.append({'event_date__count': 0,
                                'event_type': type,
                                'event_week': date})

dict_list
```

Output:

```
[{'event_date__count': 5,
  'event_type': 'NO',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 5)},
 {'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'NO',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)},
 {'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'CL',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)},
 {'event_date__count': 2,
  'event_type': 'PV',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)},
 {'event_date__count': 0,
  'event_type': 'CL',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 5)},
 {'event_date__count': 0,
  'event_type': 'PV',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 5)},
 {'event_date__count': 0,
  'event_type': 'TT',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 5)},
 {'event_date__count': 0,
  'event_type': 'TT',
  'event_week': datetime.date(2018, 11, 12)}]
```

Comment: thanks, I got confused of the multiple loops but now it clear. :)

Comment: @Tamas still if you have any queries, let me know.